# Вопрос про front-end. [Java]

Tags: java, frontend, backend

Если Java используется в основном для back-end, то что использовать для front-end?

К примеру, я хочу приложение на Windows или на Linux.

JavaFX и Swing не хочется использовать, тк все нервы угробил на это.

Comment: Используйте то, что не гробит ваши нервы.

Comment: Интересны причины угробления нервов, может все же что-то просто непонято?

Comment: @ezhov_da писал приложение для ресторана на java, потом психанул и сделал андроид приложение, чтобы клиент заказывал еду, андроид приложение для официантов и для хостес и с помощью HTML и PHP создал админку, принятие заказов для кухни.

Comment: @PauloBerezini почему вы так думаете? Разве он не отвечает предельно точно на текущую формулировку вопроса?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev шуточный ответ, по моему мнение, без какой то сути или помощи выбора решения

Comment: @PauloBerezini никаких шуток. Никто не может знать на сколько крепки нервы автора вопроса, и что их "гробит", а что нет. Эмоциональная реакция вообще субъективна. Поэтому другой ответ невозможно дать в принципе.

Comment: Нужно уточнить что именно не устраивает в Java FX и Swing. Это позволит понять чего Вы ожидаете от front-endа и даст возможность рекомендовать устраивающую Вас альтернативу (если она есть).

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать js и завернуть его в electron

Вариантов для клиентской разработки не много, если знаете C# то можете на нем

Answer (score 0):

Во все времена для *front-end* разработки использовались следующие языки: HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Это то, что, скажем так, проверено временем. Разработка *веб-страниц* используя данные языки простая и очень удобная. Возникает *вопрос*: **А почему не использовать связку Java + HTML + CSS + JavaScript**? *Ответ* простой: **Нам нужно каким-то образом отображать динамическое содержимое**.

Для решения этой проблемы в платформе *Java Enterprise Edition* были разработаны *View Techologies*: **[JavaServer Pages](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html)**, **[JavaServer Faces](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-intro.htm#BNAPH)**. Страницы *jsp* и *jsf* очень похожи на *HTML*-страницу, но все же есть минусы.

1. Если Вы заходите взглянуть на Вашу *jsp* или *jsf* страницу, то не сможете сделать это просто открыв файл (*.jsp* или *.jsf*) с помощью, допустим, Google Chrome, так как они имеют дополнительные теги и специальный синтаксис, который браузер не умеет обрабатывать. Вы увидите то, что видите в блокноте (код).
2. Интеграция, с такими замечательными библиотеками как *Bootstrap*, не такая простая.

Проблем, перечисленных выше, удалось избежать в **[Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/index.html)**. Советую обратить особое внимание на эту технологию. Есть возможность интеграции со **[Spring](https://spring.io/)**, а разрабатывать приложения с помощью Spring одно удовольствие ;)

Использовать *JavaFX* и *Swing* для разработки веб-страниц конечно же можно, но крайне нежелательно. Намного лучше использовать технологии указаны выше.